# Page is constanctly loading when I choose a option using jQuery ddSlick JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin to show the Dropdown flags on my website:

designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

**Now, the HTML code is like that:**

```
<?php   
$object   = get_queried_object();
$slug     = $object->slug;
?>
<select id="countryFlags">
     <option value="">--Choose Country--</option>
     <option value="somalia" <?php if( isset( $slug ) && $slug == 'somalia' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> data-imagesrc="//mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/somalia-2.svg" data-description="&nbsp;">Somalia</option>
     <option value="ethiopia" <?php if( isset( $slug ) && $slug == 'ethiopia' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> data-imagesrc="//mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/ethiopia-1.svg"  data-description="&nbsp;">Ethiopia</option>
     <option value="kenya" <?php if( isset( $slug ) && $slug == 'kenya' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> data-imagesrc="//mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/kenya-1.svg"  data-description="&nbsp;">Kenya</option>
     <option value="somaliland" <?php if( isset( $slug ) && $slug == 'somaliland' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> data-imagesrc="//mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/somaliland-1.svg"  data-description="&nbsp;">Somaliland</option>
     <option value="djibouti" <?php if( isset( $slug ) && $slug == 'djibouti' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> data-imagesrc="//mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/djibouti.png"  data-description="&nbsp;">Djibouti</option>
</select>
```

**and jQuery code is**

```
$('#countryFlags').ddslick({    
     width:150,    
     selectText: 'Select your preferred social network',
     imagePosition:'left',
     defaultSelectedIndex : null,
     onSelected: function(selectedData){
          if( selectedData.selectedData.value) {
               console.log( selectedData.selectedData.value );
               window.location.href = 'mysite.com/advert-location/'+selectedData.selectedData.value;
          }
     }   
});
```

**What I need:**

I want when people choose any selection then it's redirecting to a **URL + the selected value**

For example, You choose Kenya then it should redirect to you to this URL:

> mysite.com/advert-location/kenya

**Now,** As you can see the script that it's **by default** getting the value of the selected option when the page is a load that's why my page is constantly loading and loading with my given condition on the jQuery part.

It's should be load one time.

is there anyting I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have search but didn't find any `change` event that can be apply to `ddSlick` so as an alternative you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and store some value in it whenever your page gets loads for the first time and check if the value in storage is `null` or not depending on that you can redirect to other page.

Your **jquery** code will look like below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  localStorage.clear(); //clear previous data on page load

  $('#countryFlags').ddslick({
    width: 150,
    selectText: 'Select your preferred social network',
    imagePosition: 'left',
    defaultSelectedIndex: null,
    onSelected: function(selectedData) {
      if (selectedData.selectedData.value) {
        console.log(selectedData.selectedData.value);
        checking(selectedData.selectedData.value); //call function
      }
    }
  });


  function checking(value) {
    //if there is no value in localStorage
    if (localStorage.getItem("save") == null) {
      //don't redirect
      console.log("i am in don't redirect")
      var save = "firsttime";
      console.log(save);
      localStorage.setItem("save", save); //add data to storage


    } else {
      console.log("i am in redirect");
      //redirect
      window.location.href = 'mysite.com/advert-location/' + value;

    }

  }
})
```